# Webserver and MySQL server on same machine "Error :(28000/1045) Access denied for user "

Tags: php, mysql, apache

**Some details first ::**
Running MySQL 5.6 on Ubuntu 14.10 LTS with Apache as webserver.
Server sits behind a router so port 80 and 3306 are forwarded and ok.
Webserver running fine.

MySQL user list :

```
mysql> select user, host from mysql.user;
+------------------+-------------------+
| user             | host              |
+------------------+-------------------+
| userA            | %                 |
| root             | 127.0.0.1         |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost         |
| phpmyadmin       | localhost         |
| root             | localhost         |
| userA            | localhost         |
| root             | elite81           |
+------------------+-------------------+
```

**my.cnf file**  :

`[client]

```
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
```

`

Problem ::
Only 'root' has access to MySQL databases.. I want access using 'userA' but I get following error codes :

**A) when host value in php code is : external IP address of server**

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'userA'@'router.asus.com' (using password: YES)
```

**B) when host value is : 127.0.0.1**

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'userA'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Failed attempts to correct this :

Hashed bind address / 
changed bind address to 192.168.1.87 (local ip address) / 
changed bind address to external IP address /

Also tried connecting while within the network- did not work /

Also done FLUSH PRIVILEGES; in MySQL.

Gone through several related posts on the web but not solved ! :-(
Need help.

Also, I have a question.
What should be the host in php connection file when the webserver runs on same machine as the MySQL server ?

Comment: Additional Info:
I can connect on machine as `mysql -u userA -p -hlocalhost`
but not as `mysql -u userA -p -h11.11.11.11`

Comment: Dropped `userA@% `  to check : did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

1. Made a new user in MySQL (with grant privilege and full rights over all databases) accessing from any host; then `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`.
2. In php connection, host as external ip address of the server.
3. In my.cnf file , bind address : 0.0.0.0
4. Then connection succeeded.
5. Trimed down the privileges of the new account. (No administration rights, no maintenance rights, only usage of one database.)
6. Done.